# What noun describes how much a tag is used?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I say "tag", I mean the tags we have on StackExchange, and imageboards or other websites which use a tagging system. Is there a single noun to describe how many things the tag applied to? [single-word-requests](/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) has ~4500 questions to which it applies, so I could say for example:

> The [noun] of the single-word-requests tag is about 4500.

"Strength" comes to mind, but I would imagine that word is more applicable in military contexts. Is there such a word?

I realise there are far more elegant solutions without a single noun. I'm looking for a concise field name for a Tag table in a database. The field describes how many entities to which the tag applies. So it would look something like:

```
Tag(_TagID_, TagName, [NumberOfXWithThisTag])
```

And the SWR tag could look like:

```
(0016, single-word-requests, 4481)
```

Comment: There may already be a term for this, have you tried asking on meta?

Comment: The number of questions in the tag is about 4500. There are about 4500 questions in the tag. The tag has about 4500 questions. Plain and clear English, very few words, so many alternatives to choose from. Why reinvent the wheel instead?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a concise field name for a field describing the number of entities to which a tag applies, in a relational database.

Comment: I've edited the OP to clarify this as I realise I was unhelpfully vague.

Comment: @kris, is it on-topic for meta? I thought it was more ELU than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `TagCount`. It follows the usual terminology in getting sums from a database.

Comment: Sounds good to me :).

Answer (score 0):

> The [*referent*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/referent) *total* of the single-word-requests tag is about 4500.

Comment: Also a nice solution that fits the structure I asked for. I think count works more concisely though.